# How do I generate PDF content from a node?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

We are looking for a way to convert the Drupal pages into PDF on click of a button for D8. Initially we thought we could use [Print Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/print), but that only has a D7 version.

How do you create a button in D8 so that on click, it will convert the Drupal node into a PDF keeping the current theme styling and elements appropriately? We have been unable to find any D8 modules or process that can allow for this.

Comment: You’re looking for Entity Print. If you have some technical skills, you might be able to implement a print service like AthenaPDF.

Comment: If the requirement is to print each pages, then use javascript code : <a class="print-button" href="javascript:window.print()">print</a>

Comment: @Kevin when i reviewed AthenaPDF it looks like there is a version available for a Docker image. Do you know if it works on a Drupal instance? I cannot find any documentation outside of ones found on Docker's site regarding it

Comment: It acts as a microservice, so you would run it in its own instance and call its API when necessary to return a PDF. I think it can also be run on-demand on the same server, but its been a while since I tried.

Comment: @Kevin i am going to research the on-demand approach to see if i can get that to run because not sure we can get a new instance. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve with several solutions

*Use [Entity Print Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print)*

> Entity Print allows you to print any Drupal entity (Drupal 7 and 8) or
>   View (Drupal 8 only) to PDF.
>
> The module is lightweight compared to other modules like the Print
>   module, has full test coverage and is ready to be used in production
>   for both D7 and D8.

*Use new host of print module ([Printable Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/printable))*

> This is the new home of the print module. The module makes use of
>   pdf_api module to generate PDFs.

Use [PrintFriendly Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/printfriendly) (it supports localization very good)

> The #1 Print and PDF button for your Drupal site. Printer Friendly
>   pages without coding, css, or print.css. Fast, easy, and professional.
>
> The Print Friendly & PDF button saves paper and ink when printing or
>   creating a PDF. It's fast, easy, and looks great when printed. Add the
>   button now, and your users will see the difference.
>
> How Print Friendly & PDF Works The Print Friendly & PDF button
>   automatically creates printer friendly and PDF versions of your pages
>   without the hassle of having to create a print CSS file. No coding,
>   hacking or programming required. Simply install the Print Friendly &
>   PDF plugin, activate, and choose settings for full customization. It
>   also gives your user the ability to remove images and paragraphs of
>   text, so they really only have to print exactly what they want.

*And final solution* is kind of tricky solution, instead of converting the page to PDF just  provide a print theme style for your nodes, when a user clicks on the print button (or link) trigger  `javascript:window.print()` action. most of the new OS has PDF printer build-in

By the way, I recommend PrintFriendly Module

Comment: I am testing the entity_print module and have not found a good way to theme it. I will test the other modules as well.

Comment: @user2951257 ,good, inform me with the new results.

Comment: i have found a way to theme the entity_print module. I tried the others but since entity_print provides a PDF view mode this will suffice for my needs.

Comment: I do agree that PrintFriendly is good, but our use case is to download the PDF right away. PrintFriendly gives a popup which may not be acceptable by the product owner.

Comment: @user2951257 there isa configuration to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Having a D8 custom module, a very easy way is:

1. install the mpdf library

   ```
   composer require mpdf/mpdf
   ```
2. pass your output to mpdf

   ```
   $html = 'content for my pdf';
   $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => 'sites/default/files/tmp']);
   $mpdf->WriteHTML($output);
   $mpdf->Output('file.pdf', 'D');
   exit;
   ```

You should also add mpdf as dependency in your composer.json. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/add-a-composerjson-file